# Angular NgForm problema al resetearlo

Tags: angular, angular5, webforms

Tengo un **form** de solo un **input** que busca un **user por id** . Si existe lo carga en otro **form** que esta al lado, este nuevo **form** tiene un **boton** que habilita la edicion del **mismo** . En este punto ya puedes editar el **form** que has obtenido por el **id user**  y guardarlo con un **boton** que se **desbloqueara**  una vez hagas **click** en el **boton editar** .

Ahora bien, si una vez editado el **form** queremos volverlo a **deshabibilitar**    los datos del **form** del **usuario** se deberia **RESETEAR** con los datos que se habian obtenido. Y es ahi mi problema, creo que es algo muy tonto pero no consigo dar con la tecla.

Una vez puesto en **situacion** dejo a continuacion el **codigo** :

**usuario.component.html**

```
<style>
    input {
      width: 50%;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form #formSearchUser="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="buscarUsuario()" >
          <h1>Buscar Usuario</h1>
          <label>Introduce el ID del Usuario que deseas buscar</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="id" #id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user._id">
          <br>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Buscar Usuario</button>

      </form>



    </div>


    <div class="col-md-6">

     <form #formDetailUser="ngForm" *ngIf="mostrar"  >
        <h1>Usuario Encontrado</h1>
        <label>Nombre: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre" #nombre="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.nombre" [disabled]="!editable">
        <br>
        <label>Apellido 1: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="apel_1" #apel_1="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.apel_1"  [disabled]="!editable" >
        <br>
        <label>Apellido 2: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="apel_2" #apel_2="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.apel_2" [disabled]="!editable" >
        <br>
        <label>Email: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" #email="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.email" [disabled]="!editable" >
        <br>
        <label>Fecha Nacimiento: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fecha_nacimiento" #fecha_nacimiento="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.fecha_nacimiento"  [disabled]="!editable">
        <br>
        <!-- Slider -->
        <div class="form-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" (click)="activarEdicion(this.formDetailUser)"> Editar</button>
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" *ngIf="editable" style="margin-left:10px;">Actualziar datos</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    </div>  

  </div>
```

**usuario.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Usuario } from '../models/usuario';
import { usuarioService } from '../services/usuario.services';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buscar-usuario',
  templateUrl: './buscar-usuario.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./buscar-usuario.component.css'],
  providers:[usuarioService]
})
export class BuscarUsuarioComponent implements OnInit {
color = 'blue';
  user: Usuario;
  public mostrar = false;
  public editable = false;

  user_aux:Usuario;

  constructor(private usuarioService:usuarioService) {
    this.user = new Usuario("", "", "", "", "", new Date());

  }

  ngOnInit() {


  }

  buscarUsuario() {
    if (!this.user._id) {
      alert('Campo vacio !!')
    }
    else{
      this.usuarioService.get(this.user).subscribe(
        data =>{
         if (data["status"] == 200) {
            this.user = data['usuario'];
            this.user_aux = this.user;
            this.mostrar =  true;
            // console.log('USUARIO CON ID = '+this.user._id+" HA SIDO ENCONTRADO CON EXITO !!");
           // console.log(this.user);

         }

         if (data["status"] != 200){
          alert(data['message'])
          this.user = {_id:"",nombre:"",apel_1:"",apel_2:"",email:"",fecha_nacimiento:new Date};
          this.mostrar = false;
         }

        }
      );
    }



  }



  activarEdicion(f:NgForm){
    this.editable = !this.editable;
    console.log('EDITABLE = '+this.editable)
    if (this.editable == false) {
      f.setValue({
        'nombre':this.user_aux.nombre,
        'apel_1':this.user_aux.apel_1,
        'apel_2':this.user_aux.apel_2,
        'email':this.user_aux.email,
        'fecha_nacimiento':this.user_aux.fecha_nacimiento
      });  
    }
    else{

    }



    console.log('_______________________________________________')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias maneras de lograr esto con tu código actual. 
La primera es haciendo un reset sobre la variable del form, ej:
Debes cambiar tu código así:

```
<form #formDetailUser="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formDetailUser)" *ngIf="mostrar">
```

luego en el .ts asi:

```
onSubmit(formDetailUser: NgForm) {
        formDetailUser.resetForm();
}
```

Otra forma es que cuando usas `[(ngModel)]=""` mapeas el valor del input a una variable, en este caso user.x por lo que para resetearlo simplemente "resetea" la variable user ej: `this.user = new Usuario("", "", "", "", "", new Date());`

No se si este proyecto es para aprendizaje o algo que vas a utilizar, igualmente permite aclarar varios puntos, nunca o mejor dicho "casi nunca" uses esta forma,  llamada Template Driven Forms, de crear forms en Angular. Utiliza reactive form, puedes leer acerca de ella aquí: [Reactive Form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). En un proyecto sencillo puede parecer demasiado pero cuando necesitas escalar es una maravilla, además es la forma recomendada. He visto personas no acceder a puestos de trabajo por no utilizar Reactive Forms en la prueba de solicitud. Otro asunto que quizás también tenga que ver con que sea una pregunta pero igual te lo comento, nunca y bajo ningún concepto utilices español(o otro idioma que no sea ingles) en tu código, ya puedes ser messi o cristiano del mundo del software que si traes código en español estas despedido, así de simple.

Answer (score 0):

Asi me funciono perfecto, ya que al poner simplemente reset o se quedaban en rojo los inputs o se borraban al tratar de enviar.

```
<form
#productForm
[formGroup]="productsForm"
(ngSubmit)="addProductItem(); productsForm.valid?productForm.reset(): null;"
>

<button type="submit">
    Guardar
</button>
```